# Bash for loop with Parenthesis working in linux and not in Git Bash

Tags: linux, bash, cygwin

i have simple bash loop which is working fine in linux and not in local Git Bash which based on cygwin in windows
i have this for loop :

```
  #!/bin/bash

    for (i=2; i<4; ++i); do
        echo "dddd"
    done
```

in Git Bash it gives me this error :

```
./test.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./test.sh: line 5: ` done
```

### linux version of bash

Amazon Linux version 20xx.0x is available.
[user1 ~]$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later

### Git bash version

GNU bash, version 4.3.46(2)-release (i686-pc-msys)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need TWO parentheses:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i=2; i<4; ++i)); do
    echo "dddd"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your line endings from CRLF to LF. There are many ways to do this. Your favourite editor may have an option to change line endings, and also to preserve the existing line endings when saving files.

The simplest method though, is to use `dos2unix`. To convert in-place, use `dos2unix bashtest.sh`.